# Quick look menu like UBER iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am looking to build an app with a [menu like Uber](https://media.giphy.com/media/xUPGcwyq0pSNUGX9fO/giphy.gif).
I am pretty new to developing in XCODE, I have built some simple apps already but nothing with something like that, I think I have to do some kind of [ViewController that I can swipe up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOVX9.png), all I have left is how I can Make it swipe up.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably be using a third-party solution for that. For instance, [try this one](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu).

Comment: @PauloMattos I've looked into those already but am not sure if this will work from bottom to top, since they are all side menus, would I be able to change directions easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do recommend you investigate this [source](https://github.com/cocoatoucher/AICustomViewControllerTransition/blob/master/Source/AICustomViewControllerTransition.swift) for similar [tool](https://github.com/cocoatoucher/AICustomViewControllerTransition).

But if I were you I better use **UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator** instead **UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning**.

But be aware UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator available from iOS 8.

Good luck!

Comment: Looks perfect for my case! Thanks